# mod_rewrite to make a short URL

Tags: apache, wordpress, mod-rewrite, short-url

I have a url like:

```
http://skepticalgamer.com/category/slam-the-controller
```

I'd like to strip out "category" from the URL.  So I'd want:

```
http://skepticalgamer.com/slam-the-controller
```

to act as if it were the original URL above.  Is that something that can be done with mod_rewrite?

Comment: This is a Wordpress blog and I believe it's done via rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the category base is easily done with [Wordpress Plugins » WP No Category Base](http://wordpresssupplies.com/wordpress-plugins/no-category-base/), making changes in .htaccess unnecessary. The plugin doesn't permanently change URLs in the database, so if you disable the plugin, you get your category base back with no 404s for posts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could do this with mod_rewrite by doing something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^slam-the-controller$ category/slam-the-controller
```

This will take the URL:

```
http://skepticalgamer.com/slam-the-controller
```

and rewrite it to:

`http://skepticalgamer.com/category/slam-the-controller`

Comment: The URL above is the only case in which I want this rule to take effect.  I don't want "anything" coming in to be prefixed with category.  I only want that full URL to be replaced by that one shorter URL.

Comment: I see, I've modified the rewrite rule for this specific case.